# How to add rows to a pandas dataframe based on dates?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3], 'Dep':[4,5,6], 'Start Date':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'], 'End Date':['2020-01-03', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-04']})

   ID  Dep  Start Date  End Date
0   1   4   2020-01-01  2020-01-03
1   2   5   2020-01-01  2020-01-01
2   3   6   2020-01-01  2020-01-04
```

I would like to split dates based on days and create new date. Something like below:

```
    ID  Dep Start Date  End Date    New Date  
0   1   4   2020-01-01  2020-01-03  2020-01-01   
1   1   4   2020-01-01  2020-01-03  2020-01-02 
2   1   4   2020-01-01  2020-01-03  2020-01-03   
3   2   5   2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-01-01    
4   3   6   2020-01-01  2020-01-04  2020-01-01    
5   3   6   2020-01-01  2020-01-04  2020-01-02       
6   3   6   2020-01-01  2020-01-04  2020-01-03
7   3   6   2020-01-01  2020-01-04  2020-01-04
```

Thank you.

Comment: can't understand your logic?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
In [392]: data['New date'] = data.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start Date'], x['End Date']), 1)

In [395]: data = data.explode('New date')

In [396]: data
Out[396]: 
   ID  Dep  Start Date    End Date   New date
0   1    4  2020-01-01  2020-01-03 2020-01-01
0   1    4  2020-01-01  2020-01-03 2020-01-02
0   1    4  2020-01-01  2020-01-03 2020-01-03
1   2    5  2020-01-01  2020-01-01 2020-01-01
2   3    6  2020-01-01  2020-01-04 2020-01-01
2   3    6  2020-01-01  2020-01-04 2020-01-02
2   3    6  2020-01-01  2020-01-04 2020-01-03
2   3    6  2020-01-01  2020-01-04 2020-01-04
```

Comment: I think `explode` is bottleneck here.

Comment: Oh. What would be better?

Comment: Can you also please add timings for lesser data?

Comment: Maybe 1000 rows.

Comment: `190 ms ± 874 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: `6.85 ms ± 282 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: Your answer maybe faster, but also involves a lot more code than mine. Let this be OP's choice what he wants.

Comment: for `999` rows `data = pd.concat([data] * 333, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important, you can use this faster solution:

```
#convert columns to datetimes
data["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Start Date"])
data["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["End Date"])

#subtract values and convert to days
s = data["End Date"].sub(data["Start Date"]).dt.days + 1

#repeat index
df = data.loc[data.index.repeat(s)].copy()

#add days by timedeltas
add = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
df['New Date'] = df["Start Date"].add(add)
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID  Dep Start Date   End Date   New Date
0   1    4 2020-01-01 2020-01-03 2020-01-01
0   1    4 2020-01-01 2020-01-03 2020-01-02
0   1    4 2020-01-01 2020-01-03 2020-01-03
1   2    5 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
2   3    6 2020-01-01 2020-01-04 2020-01-01
2   3    6 2020-01-01 2020-01-04 2020-01-02
2   3    6 2020-01-01 2020-01-04 2020-01-03
2   3    6 2020-01-01 2020-01-04 2020-01-04
```

**Timings for 3k rows**:

```
data = pd.concat([data] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: data["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Start Date"])
    ...: data["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["End Date"])
    ...: 
    ...: s = data["End Date"].sub(data["Start Date"]).dt.days + 1
    ...: 
    ...: df = data.loc[data.index.repeat(s)].copy()
    ...: 
    ...: df['New Date'] = df["Start Date"].add(pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d'))
    ...: 
10.4 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


#Mayank Porwal answer is 56 times slowier in this sample data
In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: data['New date'] = data.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start Date'], x['End Date']), 1)
    ...: 
    ...: data.explode('New date')
    ...: 
    ...: 
590 ms ± 67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```